# Entries Fields inside a Neo Field

Tags: matrix, plugin-neo

I have again some trouble with a [Neo](https://github.com/benjamminf/craft-neo) field.

I've a Neo field with different layouts. In one I will output content from some entries with a entries field.

The problem is: Sometimes I get output, sometimes I get only some of the selected entries as output and sometimes I don't get any output.

Here is my code:

```
{% nav block in entry.myContent.level(1) %}
    {% switch block.type.handle %}

        {% case 'team' %}
            <section class="block">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    {% include "_includes/elements/teamGetMember" %}
                </div>
            </section>
    {% endswitch %}
{% endnav %}
```

And here is the call of the entries field

```
{% set entries = entry.teamGetEntres %}

{% if entries | length %}
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <p class="description">{{ entry.description }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: What isn't working @alexander? Is your code getting into the for loop or not outputting what you are expecting somewhere else...

Comment: Can you post the rest of your NEO code? I am going to guess the first "set" should be something like {% set entries = block.teamGetEntres %} where "block" is what you are calling in your Neo.

Comment: Also, please don't title your requests NeoMatrix or Neo (Matrix)... they are two different fieldtypes.

Comment: @AbbeyDesign Sorry, I send the wrong post content. I've Updated my post just now.

Answer (score 1):

So it should be:

```
{% set entries = block.teamGetEntres %}
 {% if entries | length %}
  {% for entry in entries %}
    <p class="description">{{ entry.description }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

replace "entry" in `entry.teamGetEntries` with "block"

Comment: It works, thank you.